# What is the restriction on \foreach with \from and \to statements?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw an automaton using TikZ and `\foreach` statement. Below is the sample of what I have. Now, two questions I have is,

1. Is there any way to use curly braces `{,}` instead of `(,)` as I have now to label some states of the automaton? I would like to have `A{A}`, not `A(A)`.
2. `\foreach` statement does not let me draw arrows in some situations. I want to draw arrows from `A` to `A(A)` (ideally, `A{A}` after the fix) and from `A` to `A'(A)` as well, but for some reason, it does not like how I name those states with parentheses.

Is there anybody who can help me with this? I greatly appreciate it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->]
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
\foreach \name/\a in {A/90, A''/180, A(A)/270, A'(A)/0}
\node[vertex] (\name) at (\a:3cm) {$\name$};
\foreach \from/\to in {A/A'', A/A(A), A/A'(A)}
\draw (\from) -- (\to);
\end{tikzpicture}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you want the curly braces printed in the nodes. To print backslashes you have to use `\{` and `\}`, but these cannot be used in `node` names. That is, you can't do something like `\node (\{A\}) at (0,0) {A};`. As a workaround you can use a different string for the `node` name and `node` content, something like

```
\foreach \name/\word/\a in {A/A/90, A''/A''/180, A[A]/A\{A\}/270, A'[A]/A'\{A\}/0}
  \node[vertex] (\name) at (\a:3cm) {$\word$};
```

With regard to your second question, I think this is because the parenthesis confuses the parsing of the `node` name. For example, with `A(A)` as the name, you get `\node (A(A)) ...`. I guess the first closing paren is taken as the end of the name, giving the error `No shape named A(A is known`.

Two working versions of your code, one with brackets, one with braces, and the above mentioned workaround.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->]
\tikzset{vertex/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=25pt,inner sep=0pt}}
\foreach \name/\a in {A/90, A''/180, A[A]/270, A'[A]/0}
\node[vertex] (\name) at (\a:3cm) {$\name$};
\foreach \from/\to in {A/A'', A/A[A], A/A'[A]}
\draw (\from) -- (\to);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->]
\tikzset{vertex/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=30pt,inner sep=0pt}}
\foreach \name/\word/\a in {A/A/90, A''/A''/180, A[A]/A\{A\}/270, A'[A]/A'\{A\}/0}
\node[vertex] (\name) at (\a:3cm) {$\word$};
\foreach \from/\to in {A/A'', A/A[A], A/A'[A]}
\draw (\from) -- (\to);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image][image]

Comment: That is beautiful! Thank you very much for your quick response.